# Google plus ios sdk - can not dismiss the 'Recipients' screen

Tags: ios, sdk, google-plus

I'm trying to use `google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1`. But there is a problem about `Recipient` screen. If user taps the close button on the left top corner and selects `No`, then user taps the close button again and select `Yes`, the `Recipient` screen will not dismiss and will not get any response.

This problem is existing in sample code of sdk, too.

*Is there anyone that had the sale problem?*

I tested the same code in sdk, it has the same issue. I called the shareButton: function in `ShareViewController.m``

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender {
    id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [self shareBuilder];
    _shareStatus.text = @"Status: Sharing..."; 
    if (![shareBuilder open]) {
         _shareStatus.text = @"Status: Error (see console)."; 
    } 
}
```

The type of `GPPShareBuilder` is native

*Steps to reproduce:* Clicked Share function in sample code.

1. User brought to Google+ recipients screen.
2. User tap ""x"" and select ""NO""
3. User remains at the Google+ recipients screen
4. User tap ""x"" and select ""YES"" to discard post Actual: User remains on Google+ recipients screen 
   Expected: Google+ recipients screen could dismiss

Comment: welcome @xuzepei, maybe you should provide a sample of code. :)

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe, I tested the same code in sdk, it has the same issue. 

I called the shareButton: function in ShareViewController.m

- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender {
  id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [self shareBuilder];
  _shareStatus.text = @"Status: Sharing...";
  if (![shareBuilder open]) {
    _shareStatus.text = @"Status: Error (see console).";
  }
}

The type of GPPShareBuilder is native.

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe

Steps to reproduce:
Clicked Share function in sample code.

1) User brought to Google+ recipients screen. 
2) User tap ""x"" and select ""NO"" 
3) User remains at the Google+ recipients screen 
4) User tap ""x"" and select ""YES"" to discard post 

Actual: User remains on Google+ recipients screen 
Expected: Google+ recipients screen could dismiss.

Comment: I edited your question with your comments. :)